# Difference with Public, private and protected

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was solving some basic inheritance question. I came across some thing _that I dont understand the logic.  If I inherit the derived class from Base class as private , Can I even access the public members of the Base class. Here is my code,

```
    #include <iostream>

struct Shape
{
  virtual void print()
  {
    std::cout << "SHAPE" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~Shape() {}
};

struct Box : private Shape
{
  virtual void print()
  {
    std::cout << "BOX" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
  Shape* s = new Box;  //illformed ?  can't access the public members of the base. 

  s->print();

  delete s;

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your C++ compiler is broken. gcc 7.1.1 correctly issues a diagnostic, and fails to compile the code: `error: ‘Shape’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Box’`

Comment: So it mean, if I inherit as Private , shape is inaccessible to box.  yes? Similar to where we can not access the private members outisde of the class.

Comment: @ZangMingJie  I don't have teacher. I am learning just my self by reading books and tutorials. Well , I know ppl in world will comment :) :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't be able to access the public members of a base class that is inherited as private, else the purpose of private inheritance would be pointless. You shouldn't even be able to assign a pointer of type `Box*` to a variable of type `Shape*`. If your compiler processes the code and the binary prints "SHAPE" instead of "BOX" your compiler is broken indeed.

Comment: Oaky. I understand it now. Thanks alot @Murphy for the explanation. It makes sense , yes.